# Django: relating many-to-many relationships between two pairs of one-to-one related fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I've created two models in Django extending the default user and group models by using OneToOne relations. The GroupExtended and UserExtended are related through a ManyToMany relation:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, User

class GroupExtended(models.Model):
    group = models.OneToOneField(
        to = Group,
        on_delete = models.CASCADE
    )
    [other fields...]

class UserExtended(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, 
        on_delete = models.CASCADE
    )

    group = models.ManyToManyField(
        GroupExtended,
    )

    [other fields...]
```

What I would like to obtain is that, when I assign an extended group to the extended user, the associated user also change the group, if possible. Maybe this chart helps to explain myself:

[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kM9S.png)

**In other words: Is it possible to relate two many to many relationships in such a way that when I relate two fields, the corresponding one to one related fields are also associated?**

**UPDATE: CURRENT SOLUTION**

This is the best solution I found so far with your help. I overrode the user model with Abstract User and extended the Auth/Group. When I modify or create a new  extended group, auth group is also modified or created.

/models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

#Group
class GroupExtended(Group):
    [new fields...]

#Users
class User(AbstractUser):
    [new fields...]
```

I also needed to override the admin site:
/admin.py

```
from app.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

class UserAdminExt(UserAdmin):
    print(UserAdmin.fieldsets) #To get the fieldsets
    #Now I override it
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password','new_fields')}), 
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}), 
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'groups', 'user_permissions')}), 
        ('Important dates', {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}))

admin.site.register(User, UserAdminExt)
```

It seems to work...

Comment: I would suggest overriding the `User` and `Group` model. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Comment: Ok, thank you! I will try it, however, I see I can only customise the user mode, can't I? So I should also keep the GroupExtended model.

Comment: I think you can replicate this code: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L232

Comment: I finally overrode the user model and created a new model group. When re-defining the field "groups" in the user model it seems to substitute the default "groups" field and works fine. I'll update the question above with my current solution, I would appreciate if anyone could have a look as I may be missing some group functionalities that I don't know.